# Unexpected error occurred while launching entry

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have implemented a loop job in pentaho kettle. This job has "Simple evaluation" entry that checks if it should rerun the previous transformation or not based on a condition. The variable used in condition, is being set using "Set variable" step in previous transformation. The problem is that first time job runs perfectly, but when server is restarted, job stuck and throws error:

> Unexpected error occurred while launching entry.

This error comes for both transformation and "Simple evaluation", and then job stuck in loop forever.

So I have two questions here:

1. Why does this error occur?
2. If an error occurs, transformation should stop but it is forwarding the flow to "Simple evaluation" and vice versa.

Below is the image of job :
[image]

Comment: How do you know where the error comes from ? I mean, sometimes a step fails because of of an error in an other step which is (correctly) in a `try{}cach` and therefore not written in the log.

Comment: Is it possible to post an image of the job, and also a copy of the log?

Comment: Below is the error log -[ERROR 14/02/2018 12:02:23,799] com.ephesoft.dcma.util.logger.EphesoftLoggerImpl.error(EphesoftLoggerImpl.java:39) - cleanup_job - org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
Unexpected error occurred while launching entry [Should Rerun advance_cleanup.0]

Unexpected error occurred while launching entry [advance_cleanup.0]